# Imagick (Imagemagick on PHP): serve a file without saving to disk first?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to use Imagemagick (actually PHP's [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)) to create and output (serve) an image without saving it to disk first.

Currently I'm having to save the file and then use [verot upload](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) class to serve the image.

(Apache 2 server, PHP5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. This should work for you:

```
$image = new Imagick();
// Do your image creation stuff. Make sure to set $image->setImageFormat();

header('Content-Type: image/filetype'); // Change filetype
echo $image;
```

Comment: Huh, I really was missing something simple!

I've now also seen people echoing $image->getImageBlob();

Is there any difference?

Comment: jezmeck: not really; Imagick::__toString() uses getImageBlob(). I think the reason you might see that from time to time is because the Imagick class didn't implement __toString() until 2.0.0-b1, which requires PHP 5.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

I admit to never having used Imagick, but just looking at the [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php), `echoing` the image should work just fine:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

echo $image;
```