# Return the contents of an image in php file?

Tags: php, image

I really do not know any PHP but I'd love to do one simple thing:
I access a php page from within a `<img src="/myhumbleimage.php" />` and I'd like to have an image returned from another URL.

---

I came up with:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('i' . rand(1,3) . '.png');
exit;
```

And it works:
[Avatar selection http://vercas.webuda.com/img.php?.png](http://vercas.webuda.com/img.php?.png)
(Reload the page a few times!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imagick (Imagemagick on PHP): serve a file without saving to disk first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369739/imagick-imagemagick-on-php-serve-a-file-without-saving-to-disk-first)

Comment: @Mark That question is about delivering images generated by Imagick. Whilst some elements are similar (delivery of content-type headers), it's hardly a duplicate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

The basic idea is you send the appropriate MIME type headers (using header()) then deliver the file contents using `readfile()`.

For example

```
<?php
// myhumbleimage.php

// Do whatever myhumbleimage.php does before the image is delivered

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('path/or/url/of/image/file.jpg');
exit;
```

Comment: "I really do not know any PHP". Can you just show me a working example, like if I were totally stupid?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reference the image directly then? If you are trying to hide the fact you are pulling an image from an external source, that external source will still be able to tell you are pulling their images.

Otherwise, pass a Content-Type header with the appropriate mime-type and echo the results of `file_get_contents($imageUrl)`.

Comment: Because I'd like to return a random image each time.

Comment: Ok.  :) Just thought I'd put out the warning just in case. Some people are shady that way.

Comment: @simshaun: I know it is an old story, but are you saying Google is doing all sorts of shady things? Wondering where you draw the line?

Comment: @ssh: Trying to hide the fact that you are using somebody else's photo and cataloging images across the web (while referencing the source) are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate or read, then output the image using PHP.

```
...get image data from file or dynamically...
header('Content-type: image/png'); //or whatever MIME type

print $imgdata;
```

Or check out this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered problems if I didn't also include a 'Content-Length: ' header. The problems are crawler, proxy, and browser caching related. In worst cases the browser waits until timeout for more data.

It's in the spec' and solved all issues so I've always included it even if modern browsers may work without it. Who knows, there still may be a slight delay since the browser doesn't know when it has received the last segment.

Another problem I see here is that you are assuming a .png image format.
Better to create a specific function for the purpose so you can re-use it.

```
function returnImage( $path ) {
  header( 'Content-Type: image/' . substr($path, -3) );
  header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $path ) );
  readfile( $path );
  exit;
}
```

I've made a lot of assumptions here (like the file exists and its extension is 3 characters) but this sequence seems to be the silver bullet in my experience.