# .htaccess DENY FROM ALL help?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a photo sharing website that the user can edit their picture privacy. One major concerns is that other users can see the pictures from the user that have been concidered hidden. So I though in my IMAGES directory, just put `deny from all` in a .htaccess file.

But that restricted all images from being displayed to.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks
Coulton

Comment: What kind of login mechanism do you have in place to identify users? You'll probably have to make use of that, and pass through the files after doing a login check.

Comment: A mysql_query to the database to create a session for the user. How do you pass it through files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On webservers that only allow you to put all files below the document root and not outside of it for situations like this, a .htaccess file with a deny from all directive is often used to not allow http access to a special directory and it's subdirectories.

Doing some kind of obfuscation (directory names created with the help of MD5 or SHA1 etc. functions) is not recommended.

Deliver your images with the help of a PHP function that can do all the necessary permission checks you need in your case. One easy example how to actually return the file is found here:

[Return the contents of an image in php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494704/return-the-contents-of-an-image-in-php-file)

Comment: How I'm doing it now is that I have the permission in the database. If it's private, then it won't display the image. If it isn't, then it will display the image. But I was thinking if someone got the URL, they would be able to look at it all they want when it's set as private.

Comment: Also, my directories are common. domain.com/user/picture/id << like that. If someone wanted to hack it, they could just type in a id and look at that picture.

Comment: You would place the `DENY FROM ALL` in the "picture" directory. Images are only displayed if the users allow it: If it's not private, everyone can see it. The rest depends on your concept. And the logic is in the PHP file that actually delivers the images.

Comment: How would you override `DENY FROM ALL` when it's a private picture and the user is logged in? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to. You deliver the image by a PHP script itself. Please take a look at the accepted answer in my linked stackoverflow page. It's like some kind of proxy - the PHP script hides the actual location.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But now I am stuck in my iPhone app. When requesting a UIImage it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod rewrite and a dispatcher that retrieves the file of the url. The dispatcher would also check credentials.

Example: user accesses http://mysite.com/getimage/123

Configure mod rewrite to transform this into http://mysite.com/index.php?page=getimage&att=123. Because of rewrite, no user will ever access anything else beside the index.php page unless you configure the rewrite module to do this.

index.php is the dispatcher and checks if the page really exists. If it does, it calls the controller that handles getimage.
The controller getimage checks user credentials and if the user can get the file 123, it displays 123.jpg.

This is just one variant of multiple solutions. It all depends on your site architecture.

Comment: In the database, I have the location to the image with it's privacy. I will display it if it's not private, and I won't display it when it it private. What would be my best bet?