# How would you implement private images?

Tags: php, android, image, symfony

I'm developping an App in Android which somehow has avatars like Whatsapp do. As you know, in WhatsApp you can create a group, and set a group picture for it.

I don't have any problems on taking the image, saving, etc. The problem I have is that I'm developing the webservice in Symfony2 (PHP) and I want to receive the image and save it somewhere on the server. However, obviously those images are NOT public and should be only viewed for users with permissions. I've thought about traditional method: saving the image on a folder and giving the link or not, but this is totally easy to hack.

So guys, how would you do this? Maybe saving the binary data into MySql directly? Is there any clean way to achieve this?

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer is to set the mime type of the PHP call to be an image.  A call to a URL like  `http://xxx/images.php?id=8989031289130` would then return an image instead of an HTML file.

You then have access to the PHP security context and can validate whether the user actually has permissions to view this file.

There are some more details at:
[Setting Mime type in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494704/return-the-contents-of-an-image-in-php-file)

Comment: I like this. For example, I would put all images on a folder protected from public, and it would be the server only who would fetch that image and return it via mime type, right?

Comment: The images can be anywhere.  They don't need to be available to the webserver, just to the PHP application.  The PHP application is responsible for finding the image, checking the the security and delivering the entire image back to the browser.

Comment: Ok. That's great. I will use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The typical answer here is to use a file naming scheme that precludes guessing. For example, you could take the filename plus a secret salt, hash them together, and append the hash to the filename (before the extension). Thus, what would be `/foo/bar/baz.jpg` would become `/foo/bar/baz_8843d7f92416211de9ebb963ff4ce28125932878.jpg`.

So long as your hash salt remains secret, filenames are more or less mathematically protected from random or brute-force discovery. This is, for example, the core of how Facebook protects its' users pictures without having to actually require authentication for each image request (which doesn't scale well at all).

Comment: The problem that facebook has, is that if you press copy image link, you can send it to any1 and everyone will be able to see it, and that's not good.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán Well that cannot be fixed anyway, if you see picture in the browser - you can always save it for later use.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán You can't fix that problem, ever. If the data gets sent to a client, it can be replicated and sent to other people. You can make it harder by serving images with an authentication script in front of them, but this will mean you can't use a CDN and will spend significant CPU serving images. It doesn't scale.